# How to read and write compressed sequence file in spark using Python with any supported compression codec

Tags: pyspark, compression, sequencefile

How to read and write compressed `SequenceFile` in Spark using Python.

I am using Spark 1.6 on CDH 5.12 Quickstart VM with Python 2.7

Found example as below, but not working.

`rdd.saveAsSequenceFile(<path location>, Some(classOf[compressionCodecClass]))`

`sparkContext.sequenceFile(<path location>,
                           classOf[<class name>],
                           classOf[<compressionCodecClass >]);`

Need working code to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a compressed `sequencefile` in Pyspark, use below code:

```
`myRDD = sparkcontext.sequenceFile("FILE_PATH")`
```

In Hadoop, we can find various supported compression codecs in core-site.xml file.

Few of the popular ones are:

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec
```

To write a `Sequencefile` using any of these compression codecs in Pyspark, use code as below (for GzipCodec):
  `MYrdd.saveAsSequenceFile("FILE_PATH","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")`